# Remove all items in PriorityQueue with value less than x

Tags: scala, priority-queue, a-star

Is there a way to remove all items in a scala priority queue with a value less than a specified value?

eg.

```
val queue = scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue[Int]()
queue.enqueue(3)
queue.enqueue(5)
queue.enqueue(10)
queue.enqueue(8)
queue.removeAllLessThan(6)
println(queue) // PriorityQueue(10, 8)
```

I know you could do this using a filter but it seems like there would be a very efficient way of doing this on a heap.

The reason I want to do this is to keep the memory footprint low for an A* algorithm.

Comment: Removing all items less than a certain value requires rebuilding the heap. I assume that using a filter would also scan the heap to remove unwanted items, and then rebuild the heap. So I would expect the filter to be reasonably efficient.

Answer (score 1):

In `PriorityQueue` ordering is prevailed for insertion, namely a new element is inserted in the position where ordering is guaranteed. In this case using the default ordering on `Int` (greater than),

```
queue.takeWhile(_ > 6)
```

iterates over the queue while the predicate holds, in contrast with the filter which scrutinises each and every item.